# Crystal Reports Formula Workshop boolean condition to string

Tags: string, crystal-reports, boolean

I'm currently trying to create a report using Crystal Reports that comes with Visual Studio 2008.

I would like to include a field of type boolean on my report that shows a string rather than true or false. The string should contain either contain a € or a % sign.

How would I go about doing this in the Formula Workshop?

I've tried things like e.g.

```
if {tblAankoopDetails.SoortKorting} = true then "€" else "%"
```

However this never seems to work and results in warnings such as "The formula result must be a number".

This should be fairly simple but this is my first go at using Crystal Reports.

Help would be much appreciated.

Jay

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your SoortKorting field has always true or false. Maybe there's a null and in that case your formula will not work.

Try with this:

```
if isnull({tblAankoopDetails.SoortKorting}  ) then 
" "
else
    if {tblAankoopDetails.SoortKorting} =true 
    then "€" else "%"
```

Comment: As you suggested there currently are fields containing a null. I obviously hadn't thought about catching that exception if you hadn't mentioned it. 

What you suggested works like a charm, even without the code preceding 'else'. I think what I did wrong was try to format edit the actual boolean text field rather than create a formula from scratch and drag that onto the report.

In short, thank you very much for your swift reply including bonus suggestion :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is nothing else in the same formula. Usually I see that particular error when a formula sometimes returns a string, and sometimes a number.

Also, you shouldn't need to test for true, so you might try:

```
if {tblAankoopDetails.SoortKorting} then "€" else "%"
```

Comment: So you can omit 'true'? I wasn't sure whether you could do that. However, as stated below I think I was simply trying to edit the 'item' itself rather than creating a formula from scratch, my bad.

Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Jay expression returns true. So you are doing expression = true or true = true. This is a useless equality comparison.